# firebase authorization and subscription to insert only events

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below code snippet works for subscribing to firebase events - insert , update , delete - all of them.

- **Is there a way to subscribe to only INSERT ?**

  ```
   var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('user/xxxx/unread');            
   starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
            console.log(snapshot.val());
   });
  ```
- Also if there are 4 subscribers to same node like 'user/xxx/**unread**' and after first subscriber has read the message, the message has to be moved to 'user/xxx/**read**', can we do it transactionally from javascript client so that only 1 of subscribers change state in firebase.
- Finally after third party authentication with firebase , can we do an **authorization** in firebase that a user xxx can only see user/xxx/ node ? In this way even if user xxx changes in javascript xxx to yyy, user gets no notifications in that case.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 'child_added' event, does the point 1.

```
 var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('user/xxxx/unread');            
 starCountRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
          console.log(snapshot.val());
 });
```

Also this event only sends 1 value that is added to client which removes the need for moving items from unread to read since previously 'value' was returning all data

For authentication :
[examples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens)

For authorization :
[examples](https://github.com/firebase/firechat/blob/master/rules.json)